# VBA - Problems with selection if called from another module

Tags: excel, vba

I've ran into an issue when trying to call a module from within another one. The code that I'm executing is the following

```
Sub deleteLine()
Dim list As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Set list = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")
counter = list.Cells(list.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1
If counter = 0 Then
MsgBox ("Why?")
Else:
list.Range("A" + CStr(counter + 1)).EntireRow.Delete
End If
CreateDiagram
list.Select
End Sub
```

Now the lines in "CreateDiagram" that cause the error look like this

```
Dim dia As Worksheet
Set dia = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Diagram")
    dia.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    Selection.Group
    dia.Range("A1").Select
```

Now what I don't understand is that when I try to execute CreateDiagram directly it works just fine. Any idea where the error might come from?

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Oh right my bad, "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: and line that causes the error is `dia.Shapes.SelectAll`?

Comment: @timp95 Which line gives the error?  I *assume* that `dia` is a Worksheet - but you might want to include slightly more of the `CreateDiagram` code, so that this becomes a [mcve]

Comment: the lines causing an error are  `Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter`
`Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle`


Dia is indeed a worksheet. I edited my original post accordingly

Comment: Is `Sheets("Diagram")` the ActiveSheet when the error **does not** raise? `Selection` returns the ActiveObject selected (cell, shape, etc.), **on the active sheet** [Application.Selection property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection) so I think you need to activate `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Diagram")` before line `dia.Shapes.SelectAll`

Comment: Yep, activating the worksheet did the trick. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I run this

```
dia.Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
Selection.Group
dia.Range("A1").Select
```

...and it's not causing an error.

**Unless**, the shapes have already been grouped in a previous execution. In that case, `Selection.Group` will give you:

`Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`

So, making sure that your shapes are first un-grouped and then selected and grouped, should fix your issue.

```
Dim dia As Worksheet
Set dia = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Your worksheet's name")
dia.Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.Ungroup
dia.Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
Selection.Group
dia.Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: They aren't previously grouped and if try to ungroup them it produces an error on it's own. As I said, running the code on it's own works just fine, it only produces an error if I try to run it from another module

Comment: @timp95 Well that's odd.. It works fine for me regardless where I'm calling it from. Are you sure there are more than one shapes in your worksheet? When you say "from another module" you mean from another `sub` or an actual `module`? Because when you're calling subs across modules you should call them like : `call module1.CreateDiagram`

Comment: Yep, there are more than one shape and I think the alignment lines are the problem rather than the grouping. I'm calling it from a sub in another model another module.

Comment: @timp95 So, to test the sub, you first run it and then, if you want to run it for a second time, you first ungroup the shapes manually and then run it again? I suggest you post the rest of the code, because other than what I said in my answer, I don't see anything wrong with it. As I said, I am currently running this very code from wherever I want to, without any problems.

Comment: @timp95 I also suggest you use the `.Worksheets` collection instead of `.Sheets` when you want to refer to a worksheet.

Comment: As @FoxfireAndBurnAndBurns pointed out, the error was resolved by activating the sheet before using the selection. Thank you very much for your help regardless :)